# jQuery Live Form Validation by Geek Tantra

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using the Geek Tantra jQuery Live Form Validation found [here:](http://www.geektantra.com/2009/09/jquery-live-form-validation-version-1-1/)

Geek Tantra site Advanced Demo: [Click Here](http://www.geektantra.com/projects/jquery-form-validate/advanced_demo/)

Geek Tantra site Project Repository: [Click Here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-form-validate/)

I also made a [JsFiddle here:](http://jsfiddle.net/Gq46w/)

What I am trying to do is have a message pop up at the bottom of the page saying that there is an error on the page if ANY field has an error. I hard coded an example in my JsFiddle.

I tried putting a "flag" in the validation code such as this:

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
errorFlag = FALSE;
jQuery("#ValidField").validate({
expression: "if (VAL){ return true; errorFlag = TRUE;} else return false;",
message: "Please enter the Required field"
});
jQuery("#ValidNumber").validate({
expression: "if (!isNaN(VAL) && VAL){ return true; errorFlag = TRUE;} else return false;",
message: "Please enter a valid number"
});
jQuery("#ValidInteger").validate({
expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[0-9]*$/) && VAL){ return true; errorFlag = TRUE;} else return false;",
message: "Please enter a valid integer"
});
jQuery("#ValidDate").validate({
expression: "if (!isValidDate(parseInt(VAL.split('-')[2]), parseInt(VAL.split('-')[0]), parseInt(VAL.split('-')[1]))) return false; else return true;",
message: "Please enter a valid Date"
});
jQuery("#ValidEmail").validate({
expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[^\\W][a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-\\.]+([a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-\\.]+)*\\@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/)){ return true; errorFlag = TRUE;} else return false;",
message: "Please enter a valid Email ID"
});
jQuery("#ValidPassword").validate({
expression: "if (VAL.length > 5 && VAL){ return true; errorFlag = TRUE;} else return false;",
message: "Please enter a valid Password"
});
jQuery("#ValidConfirmPassword").validate({
expression: "if ((VAL == jQuery('#ValidPassword').val()) && VAL){ return true; errorFlag = TRUE;} else return false;",
message: "Confirm password field doesn't match the password field"
});
jQuery("#ValidSelection").validate({
expression: "if (VAL != '0'){ return true; errorFlag = TRUE;} else return false;",
message: "Please make a selection"
});
jQuery("#ValidMultiSelection").validate({
expression: "if (VAL){ return true; errorFlag = TRUE;} else return false;",
message: "Please make a selection"
});
jQuery("#ValidRadio").validate({
expression: "if (isChecked(SelfID)){ return true; errorFlag = TRUE;} else return false;",
message: "Please select a radio button"
});
jQuery("#ValidCheckbox").validate({
expression: "if (isChecked(SelfID)){ return true; errorFlag = TRUE;} else return false;",
message: "Please check atleast one checkbox"
});
jQuery('.AdvancedForm').validated(function(){
if (errorFlag = TRUE) alert("Error on page.");
else alert("Use this call to make AJAX submissions.");
});
});
<script>
```

...which did not work.

I am doing this because my form is long. If you are at the bottom of the form, hit "SUBMIT," AND have an error on the page, nothing happens. The user is left there thinking the form is not working. My JsFiddle shows a good example of this if you correctly fill ALL fields EXCEPT the first field (leave it blank).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you're using the Geek Tantra Validation plugin then you're not using the [tag:jquery-validate] plugin.  Please be more careful when tagging your question.  You also should follow the guidelines here:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood the tag; i am using jQuery validate functions (not the plug in). Now can you help me out with an answer?